# UILabel provides nil value

Tags: swift, uilabel, option-type

I have two view controllers. 1st view controller fetches the user's location and has a delegate method. 2nd view controller conforms to the delegate method of 1st VC. I have a UILabel in 2nd VC which displays the location received from delegate method.

```
@IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!
func locationOfTheUser(location: String) {
locationLabel.text=location
}
```

The locationLabel is connected in IB as an reference outlet.
But when i run the program it gives me an error saying that unexpectedly found nil value while unwrapping the optional.

Comment: Check that delegate is properly set or not.

Comment: make sure the label is initialized at the time you `func locationOfTheUser(location: String)` , also when do you call this function?

Comment: @John I have created the label in IB with a predefined value. So do I need to initialise it explicitly?

Comment: @NiravD yeah, it is set properly. I am able to get the value of the first VC. The only problem I face is with UILabel

Comment: Check location string maybe you pass nil value to delegate function

Comment: Is your controller is already loaded where you having this label? If it is not than your label is nil

Comment: @MücahitTekin location string is passing the correct value. I have printed the value on console to be sure.

Comment: @NiravD I guess you are right, My controller is not loaded when my delegate method is called. How can I make sure that delegate method is called after my view has been loaded?

Comment: @TejasviTandon For that you need to show us the flow of your app

Comment: @NiravD Its okay, I found the solution. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @TejasviTandon Welcome mate :) It's great that you found the solution :)

Comment: The controller was not loaded for me too causing the same. Thanks @NiravD for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your label like this:

```
@IBOutlet var weak locationLabel: UILabel!
```

The mention "@IBOutlet" makes Interface Builder recognize the outlet.

"Weak" is used because in most situations the owner of the outlet isn't the same as the owner of the view. For example, a view controller doesn't own someLabel - the view controller's view does.

For example, if there is a code path that removes an outlet from its superview, or the outlet is (intentionally) not hooked up in the storyboard, it needs to be an optional because the outlet is not guaranteed to be there when it's accessed.

```
@IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel?
```

If there is no code path that re-adds the outlet to the view hierarchy, it would also be good to make it weak to not hold on to it unnecessarily when it gets removed:

```
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel?
```

This ensures that if the label is removed from the superview, it's not being kept in memory by the strong reference in the view controller. In the most common case, where there is an outlet that will always be there, a strong, implicitly unwrapped optional is appropriate:

```
 @IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!
```

The outlet isn't weak in case the code ever changes so that there is a code path that removes the view from the view hierarchy but you forget to update the optionality of the property. The object will stay in memory and using it won't crash your app.

Also, "var" is used because outlets are, by definition, set after initialization

You can after put your code:

```
func locationOfTheUser(location: String) {
    locationLabel.text=location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private var locationOfUser: String?

    func locationOfTheUser(location: String) {
        locationOfUser = location
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationLabel.text = locationOfUser
    }
```

Try this. If it works, it means that the locationOfTheUser() is being called before the view of this controller has been loaded, therefore the label is not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var heartbeats: UILabel!
  guard heartbeats?.text != nil else {
        print("The label is empty")
        return
    }
```

---

To check if the uilabel is really empty.